# Inline onclick Javascript action to open gallery from button click?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, prettyphoto

I am trying to open a gallery in a lightbox from a button click.
I have the lightbox being triggered but not populated by the gallery.

http://www.crespoorganic.com/2017/02/22/experimental/

I am using Responsive Lightbox by dFactory set to prettyPhoto and the wordpress media library Gallery setting.

This is what I am using for the URL and Gallery

`#<a class="gallery-link" title="Our Story Gallery" href="#" data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1">Gallery</a>`

`[gallery link="file" class="gallery-link" columns="1" rel="lightbox-gallery-1" size="full" ids="981,980,976,975,974"]`

There is space to Insert inline onclick javascript action.
Enter onclick action code.

Does anyone know what the code would be to trigger the gallery loading in the lightbox please?